# How do I force my login page to return back to the original page if there is something wrong with the login?

Tags: html, express, ejs

I'm making a simple login page with express.js + E.js.

If the login is wrong, I have a variable `badLogin` that triggers if the login is wrong (see below), but I'd like the website to redirect back to the `login` page and not stay on the `auth` page.

Does anybody know how to make this work?

I am new to Web development so this kinda confused me.

If there is no found user:

```js
if (!targetUser) {
            await res.render('login', {
                badLogin: true
            })
        }
```

With this code, the browser stays on the /auth page, but I'd like it to redirect back to the `login` page. I was going to use `res.redirect()` but I can't use the variables that I need with that.

TLDR; User logs in -> login is wrong -> redirect **back** to the login page (not stay on the auth page) and display the error (set the variable to true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's wrong with `res.render()`

Comment: I don’t want the browser to stay on the /auth page. I want it to go back to the /login page if it fails. Render does not change the path, only changes what is viewed.

Comment: make an if statement. `if(badLogin){ window.location.href="https://your-login-page.com"; }`

Comment: @Martin But then how would I pass the variable through?

Comment: Any update on this particular issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple if statement around the login variable you already made.

```
if(badLogin){
    window.location.href="https://your-login-page.com";
}
else{
 //go to authentication etc.
}
```

Comment: How would I pass the variable then?

Comment: What vairable do you mean? You already have a boolean logic around your `badLogin` variable. When it's set to true, you enter the if statement, which will then redirect the user back to the login page. But you should really do it in a super early step and make it so that you only ever enter the authentication page when everything "is ok".

Comment: Post more of your code, it could probably be a lot more optimal in terms of what you're trying to achieve. You should do your checks early, if something is not ok, prompt your user with valuable error information (incorrect username and password or whatever), and then do nothing. Stay where you are. Only if everything is okay, you move to the next step (i.e. the authentication page).

Comment: A good practice would be to have basic javascript validation checking if the e-mail syntax is correct (if you use that for login) etc. Hold the hand of your users through everything as much as possible. It's good practice. Then do the more in-depth checks through AJAX to a PHP page. You can then throw back an error if login is incorrect, and only if everything is okay, move on.

Comment: I need to pass the badLogin variable to the E.js file. That triggers the error message on the top. But I see what you mean. I’ll try it soon and let you know.